# How can I setup apache to proxy for two different tomcats on the same server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy

I have to have two different tomcats on the same server both to be targeted by different domain names. I was wondering if it is possible for apache to proxy to both. I haven't found any documentation that with explanation to this solution yet.
I have below an example virtual host of the two I have on the server which proxies for the single tomcat instance so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName tinderbox.mycompany.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName tinderbox.mycompany.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName othername.mycompany.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9090/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9090/
</VirtualHost>
```

Essentially, repeat the VirtualHost block, change the server name so the block applies to your second domain name and change the target of the ProxyPass to whatever ports the second Tomcat instance is using.

Comment: I had forgotten to add the NameVirtualHost directive